# ssrs create role disabled

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am createing some roles for ssrs.I created groups and users in the OS level.Now I am about to create a new role in ssrs.for this,I connected to SSMS .But ssms->the  security folder--> the create new role has been disabled!!

[image]

The report server is authenticated using windows credentials with admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you use a script to create the role you will get an error message that could point to the problem?

Comment: Please be noted that ther eis no scripting is possible ,if we connect to the report server engine on ssms

Comment: IF YOU please see the above picture there is no provision to write the script

Comment: If you right-click on an existing Role it should give you the option to "Script Database Role As".   Create a scrip for an existing Role, change the name of the Role and try to run it.
This won't solve your problem - just give you some added information about what the problem might be.